# WPF fire EventHandler after property changed via Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling

My WPF-application has a window with third-party control in witch loading data. Control has methods for show and hide progress bar when data begin loading and end. I use MVVM for data binding to my controls. I need property witch indicate when data loading begin and end and this property must be accessible in code behind. I added CheckBox control in window with Visibility="Hidden" and bind it to property flag in my ViewModel, also added EventHandler on Checked event:

```
<CheckBox Name="chkIndicator" Visibility="Hidden" IsChecked="{Binding IsDataLoading}" Checked="chkIndicator_Checked" />
```

In code behind view event handler:

```
private void chkIndicator_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.chkIndicator.IsChecked.Value)
        tableViewOrders.ShowIndicator();
    else 
        tableViewOrders.HideIndicator();
}
```

In ViewModel when loading data:

```
public bool IsDataLoading
{
    get { return _isDataLoading;}
    set {
        _isDataLoading = value;
        PropertyChanged("IsDataLoading");
    }
}
...
public void MethodLoadingData()
{
    /*1*/ IsDataLoading = true;

    //here method for loading data to collection binded to tableViewOrders

    /*2*/ IsDataLoading = false;
}
```

When method MethodLoadingData execute, line /*1*/ is work fine - eventhandler chkIndicator_Checked fired, but when /*2*/ run - eventhandler doesn't fire. 
Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried changing the binding mode of "IsChecked" property to two way or something

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx